# Add custom rewrite rule in wordpress pointing to a different file

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I've been using a working rewrite rule in wordpress. Here's the code I'm using:

```
if(!function_exists('flush_rewrite_rules')):
function flush_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
endif;
add_action('init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');


if(!function_exists('create_custom_rewrite_rules')):
function create_custom_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->rules =
        array_merge(array
        (
            '^booking/([^/]+)/?$'           => sprintf('index.php?pagename=booking&lessonid=$matches[1]'),
            '^teacher/([^/]+)/?$'           => sprintf('index.php?pagename=teacher&tname=$matches[1]&tdate=%s', date("Y-m-d")),
            '^teacher/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$'   => 'index.php?pagename=teacher&tname=$matches[1]&tdate=$matches[2]'
    ), $wp_rewrite->rules);
}
endif;
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'create_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

I want to add another rewrite rule that would point to a different file:
For example, when a user go to http://mywebsite.com/api/force_cancel, it would load api.php instead of the default index.php

```
'^api/([^/]+)/?$'       => '/wp-content/themes/chico/api.php?method=$matches[1]'
```

Is it possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried re-saving your permalink structure?

Comment: Hello @noc2spamツ, what do you mean re-saving? I tried to add this: '^api/([^/]+)/?$'       => '/wp-content/themes/chico/api.php?method=$matches[1]' in rewrite rule, but it's not working. Maybe there's something wrong with that approach. I dont know.

Comment: After you add a new rewrite rule, you have to flush the rewrite rules.The easiest way to do that is by re-saving your permalink structure via Settings -> Permalinks ( just press update / save or what ever button is there).